# Вывод заданного количества файлов из каталога

Tags: php, xml

Написал вот такую вещь:

```
$files = scandir('xml/');
$file = shuffle($files);
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (!isset($_GET['id']) and preg_match('/^article.*\.xml$/i', $file)) {
        echo '
              <ul>
                  <li>' . $file . '</li>
              </ul>';
    }
}
```

Код призван выводить из каталога xml-файлы в случайном порядке, с чем, он собственно успешно справляется. Проблема только в том, что он не умеет выводить заданное количество этих самых файлов.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: `if($i++ > X) break;`

Comment: А как определить $i? «Х» — это заданное количество?

Comment: Эммм ... перед циклом $i=0; да X - заданное количество

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Я поместил вот такую конструкцию после foreach и if  `$i = 0;
  
  if($i++ > 4) break;`

Comment: как оно может работать если вы обнуляете переменную и тут же проверяете не больше ли она 4. конечно 0 меньше 4. Обнуляете перед циклом, а увеличиваете и проверяете уже внутри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий код для вашей задачи:

```
$files = scandir('xml/');
$file = shuffle($files);
$count = 777; // задаёте желаемое число
$index = 0; // счётчик
foreach($files as $file) {
    $index++;
    if ($index > $count) {
        break;
    }
    if (!isset($_GET['id']) and preg_match('/^article.*\.xml$/i', $file)) {
        echo '
            <ul>
                <li>' . $file . '</li>
            </ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Не удаётся. Выводит разное количество файлов. Может быть это потому, что в каталоге содержатся файлы в т. ч. с названиями не подходящими под '/^article.*\.xml$/i', а скрипт считает все?

Comment: Всё, разобрался)) Надо было `$index++;
    if ($index > $count) {
        break;
    }` вставить после проверки (if …). Спасибо вам!